# how to calculate data in rows with ComboBoxes as selectors?

Tags: vba, excel

[image: example]  Is it possible that I Select for example, start date 06/10/2014 in ComboBox1 and ending 6/20/2014 in ComboBox2. And when I press calculate, Excel selects rows between those dates and gather them in Sheet2, how many days selected in A1, total inpust in B1, and so on. This the code which I use for  ComboBoxes:

```
`Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
```

`Set Sheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")`

```
`With Sheet
    `ComboBox1.List = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
    `ComboBox2.List = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
`End With
```

`End Sub`

Comment: Do you want to copy the rows between those dates from Sheet1 to Sheet2? or just put the count and the sum of column b between them?

Comment: Just to count and the sum rows between them in Sheet2, Column A, B C...

Answer (score 0):

Save the selected dates into some cells on Sheet2 and then use Excel SUMIFS and COUNTIFS formulas with those dates to get your results. Will that solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This wont work as is, but hopefully it will give you an idea of one way to achieve your result.

Determine what rows your selected items correspond to

```
Row1 = CombBox1.ListIndex + 2 ' ComboBoxes have zero-based index, and your data has headers. +2 to negate these

Row2 = ComboBox2.ListIndex + 2 ' Same again..
```

Calculate the row Count

```
RowCount = Row2 - Row1
```

Sum the values (this is probably a really bad way to do it, couldn't get WorksheetFunctions to work for me though)

```
Sum = 0
R = Row1

Do
    Sum = Sum + Sheet.Cells(R,2).Value2
    R = R + 1
    If R > Row2 Then Exit Do
Loop
```